# How to view mongoid queries in new relic in rails application

Tags: rubygems, mongoid, newrelic

I'm usig "newrelic_rpm gem", Its working fine in sqllite(i.e.., embedded db in rails). when using mongoid.yml it shows sql[0] for mongoid. Also it cannot list the mongoid query in http://localhost.com:3000/newrelic/show_sample_sql?id=91570930.

Does new-relic supports mongoid?
Give the steps for including mongoid in new-relic appliction..,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preface: I work for New Relic =)

New Relic unfortunately doesn't officially support MongoDB... I was wondering if have you tried using 'rpm_contrib'?

'rpm_contrib' is community sourced instrumentation that is only authored by New Relic, but does contain instrumentation for MongoDB. It doesn't add quite the same level of depth as our official instrumentation, but often times gets the job done. It may be have you're looking for, as far as mongoid support.

https://github.com/newrelic/rpm_contrib

Please feel free to open up a ticket on our support site:

https://support.newrelic.com/

If you have any questions in the future! We're always happy to help.

Best,
Seve

Comment: rpm_contrib repository is deprecated. Now you should use https://github.com/newrelic/extends_newrelic_rpm

Answer (score 15):

I've just released a gem that adds instrumentation for Moped / Mongoid 3: https://github.com/stevebartholomew/newrelic_moped

It's literally just gone up so I'll be tidying up the project over the next few days but it's perfectly useable, logging all queries you make under the SQL tab.

Comment: Thanks for creating this, sorely needed!